# How can I fix a for loop for a list of words?

Tags: list, for-loop, tkinter, listbox, python-3.8

I created a pop up using Tkinter that would show all of the words in a list. I used a for loop so that I could insert all of the words in the Listbox that I have set up. The problem that has occurred is that the for loop is putting the words from the list reversed and inserted one letter per index. I wanted that there should be one word in a non reversed order per index.

Code:

```
for words in list:
        index = 0

        if words != 0:
            index += 1
            listbox.insert(index, words)
```

Output(Check the inside of the list box):
[image]

Comment: Show the content of variable `list`.

Comment: This is part of the list variable (the original is too long):
`["salve" , "vale" , "et" , "est" , "in" , "sunt" , "non" , "insula" , "sed" , "oppidum"
                , "quoque" , "canis" , "coquus" , "filia" , "filius" , "hortus" , "mater" , "pater" , "servus" , "via" , "amicus" , "ancilla" , "cena" , "cibus"
                , "intro" , "saluto" , "porto" , "video" , "dominus" , "laetus" , "mercator" , "audio" , "dico" , "unus" , "duo" , "tres" , "quattuor" , "quinque"
                , "sex" , "septem" , "octo" , "novem" , "decem" , "ad" , "ecce" , "magnus" , "parvus"]`

Comment: Don't use keyword `list` as variable.  You can try `for word in list: listbox.insert('end', word)`.

Comment: Each time when you iterated,the `index` will always be `1`.Maybe you need to put the `index=0` before the `for` loop.

Comment: @acw1668 I did thank you and that work. (You should write it as an answer to get credit for it)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should avoid using keyword `list` as variable.  Change it to, for example, `wordlist` instead.  Also you should insert word at the end of listbox instead of `index`:

```
for word in wordlist:  # better rename list to wordlist
    listbox.insert('end', word) # insert at the end of listbox instead
```